# Thread.currentThread().sleep(time) v/s Thread.sleep(time);

Tags: java, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Thread.currentThread().sleep(x) vs. Thread.sleep(x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077216/java-thread-currentthread-sleepx-vs-thread-sleepx)

whats the difference between...

```
Thread.currentThread().sleep(time)
```

and

```
Thread.sleep(time);
```

---

one more thing is there anyother method by which i can delay in program without using Thread Class...

Comment: This question is so close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077216/java-thread-currentthread-sleepx-vs-thread-sleepx that one shameless plagarist just cut-and-pasted the accepted answer as his answer to this question.

Comment: @Stephen C maybe it's someone else who's shameless for asking redundant questions?

Comment: @Dave - @Jazz has only asked 2 questions, and the other one wasn't redundant.  Besides, everyone knows that plagarism is cheating.  Children are taught this in primary school, and anyone who gets to university cannot failed to have learned that it is a big NoNo.

Comment: Every operation delays a Thread to some degree. However, if you specically want to introduce a delay you can; busy wait, use Object.wait(timeout), Queue.poll(timeout, TimeUnit), Selector.select(timeout), Socket.read() with a timeout or any other function which has a timeout. It all depends on why you want to delay your thread.

Answer (score 11):

[Thread.sleep()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) is a static method. There is no difference between calling `Thread.sleep()` and calling `Thread.currentThread().sleep()`. However, if you use eclipse, the latter form should give you a warning message as you are accessing the static method sleep() in a non-static way.

[TimeUnit.sleep()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#sleep(long)) is a fantastic alternative to Thread.sleep(). I personally prefer it because in most cases I want to sleep for whole seconds and I can easily and clearly do this with `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5)` as opposed to `Thread.sleep(5*1000)` or `Thread.sleep(5000)`

**Edit:** There is yet another alternative, but it is not at all a desirable alternative. Calling [Object.wait()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long)) will halt execution in a similar fashion to Thread.sleep(). However, it is inadvisable to do so because first you have to use `synchronize(Object)` and this method is intended for wait/notify Thread synchronization. Also, there is no guarantee that the Thread will wait for the full time specified as spurious wake-ups from Object.wait() are acceptable for JVM implementations.

Comment: TimeUnit itself will run Thread.sleep() 

from Java API: Perform a Thread.sleep using this unit.

Comment: @Mohammad shamsi, Yes, but using Object.wait() does not require using the Thread class. Strictly speaking though, TimeUnit is an alternative, even if the current implementation simply delegates to Thread.sleep().

Answer (score -4):

1 - they are same.

2 - Thread.sleep is the only way to delay in Java unless you implements your own way ;)

Comment: -1 because your point number 2 is incorrect. See my answer for an alternative.