# How to create a working array with images in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have been struggling to work with images using an array for my android application , i had created an array with a few images but even after i use a loop only 1 image gets loaded on the imageview i.e the last image present in the array so here only 'fourofclubs.png' is getting loaded. Basically i want to load images as a sequence using a loop on a single ImageView 'image1'.

this is my code:-

```
                  ImageView image1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                         int[] cardsdeck = 
                {
                    R.drawable.aceofclubs,
                    R.drawable.deuceofclubs,
                    R.drawable.threeofclubs,
                    R.drawable.fourofclubs,
                            };


            for ( int i = 0; i < cardsdeck.length; i++ )
            { 
                image1.setImageResource(cardsdeck[i]);

            }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here ? transitions between your images ? show everything together on the screen ?

Comment: image1.setImageResource(cardsdeck[i]);
this means every times the code executes this will show last image in array its obvious.

Comment: i want to load multiple images on a single ImageView using a loop..
but when i try to display a text using toast it gets displayed 4 times as given in the loop

Answer (score 2):

Actually You are having only one image i.e. image1.And you are assigning four images one by one to this image1.So,the last image remains there which comes after third.Either you call 4 images by its id.or u set time delay in your loop to see different images on your image1.
And make your Question more clear.

Comment: i want to load multiple images on a single ImageView using a loop..
but when i try to display a text using toast it gets displayed 4 times as given in the loop. How do i call 4 images by their id? m new to this, please help!

Comment: You are not calling any toast by its id.How is it possible to show multiple images on a single image view  at a time.But if u want to show it on that view multiple images then use sleep method inside your loop such that u are able to see multiple images on your single image view.Why is it so important for u to show all images on single image view?BTW Use this link to know about sleep method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077216/java-thread-currentthread-sleepx-vs-thread-sleepx

Answer (score 1):

Each image does go through the loading processes but the last image set is the one that will displayed. Screen rendering doesn't occur until the main thread returns to the system. So, if you were expecting to see the whole sequence, that will not occur as only the last image is rendered.

Comment: i want to show the whole sequence using the loop i.e each image should load one by one on a single ImageView

Comment: You can use either an animation or a loop on another thread which posts back the images.