# Breakpoints doesn't work when using Thread.currentThread().sleep()

Tags: java, multithreading, jboss

I am running JBoss EAP 6.3.

In one of the AuthenticationFilter.java, `Filter` class which is configured in `web.xml` I have `Thread.currentTthread().sleep(1000)` for some reason.

When I run my JBoss App in debug mode the breakpoints whichever I set even in a prior line before `Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000)` in `Filter` class doesn't work.

I would like to know is it because of the threading Mechanism.

Comment: both thread & static paradigm is not that harmful considering logic & programs..... is i so....... else it is not the way & incorrect....? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077216/java-thread-currentthread-sleepx-vs-thread-sleepx/34058957#34058957

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is because of threading Mechanism which is been used.... Basically `Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000)` makes the current thread life cycle which is in execution to go for sleep..... If you need a sleep for a while you should use `Thread.sleep()` rather....

And answering the question as `Thread.currentThread().sleep()` is recognized within present class, breakpoints whichever set will not work regardless wherever its been set within that class as class nature been recognized as thread....

**When Threads been used breakpoints won't work in debug mode, until unless Serializable also patched alongside with Runnable.**

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000)` and `Thread.sleep(1000)` do the exact same thing. I don't understand the point you are trying to make.

Comment: The point making is,- When Threads been used breakpoints won't work in debug mode, until unless Serializable also patched alongside with Runnable.

Answer (score -1):

It may because of non-execution-paradigm as I have one `CommonAuthenticationFilter.java` and `AuthenticationFilter.java` although code execution may not dismay.....

JBoss strides or not executing this dual nature as one `Filter` passes so....

Eclipse break-points are well in-spite it may....

[Debugging multiple threads in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375538/debugging-multiple-threads-in-eclipse)

But it is not.....,- as per the above discussion..... We're not discussing break-points at the,-`core` - `run()` so..... SO it is not that wrong Question...... and JBoss jDevStudio also as like Eclipse here as by SO.....

Comment: As per the discussion highlighted, embedded here.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375538/debugging-multiple-threads-in-eclipse breakpoints didn't turn up in debug mode.... if debug point set in inside `run()` method, although it skips its prior first execution breakpoints,- breakpoint been araises inside run() which is been set. So hence onwards debug mode can be examined. _**It means breakpoints didn't turn at all if thread is in use.**_ I don't understand how & why inside `run()` its obliged.... Funda of Thread should be studied by myself rather debating & disputing it. Thanks.